# Unit Test Interaction Between Activity and Service

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-activity, android-service, android-testing

How can you test the interaction between an activity and a service?

For example, I have a service that manages the current music player play queue and an activity that displays the play queue to the user. I want to test that the activity correctly displays the play queue.

```
public class ViewAvailableSongsActivityTests extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<ViewAvailableSongsActivity> {
    public ViewAvailableSongsActivityTests() {
        super(ViewAvailableSongsActivity.class);
    }

    public void testOneAvailableSong() {
        SongParcel song = new SongParcel("Test Title", "Test Artist", "content://testuri");
        addSongToAvailableList(song);

        Activity activity = this.getActivity();
        ListView lstAvailableSongs = (ListView) activity.findViewById(R.id.lstAvailableSongs);
        assertEquals(1, lstAvailableSongs.getCount());

        assertListViewItemIsCorrect(lstAvailableSongs, 0, song);

        stopMyService();
    }

    public void test3AvailableSongs() {
        SongParcel songLast = new SongParcel("Test Title", "Test Artist1", "content://testuri");
        addSongToAvailableList(songLast);

        SongParcel songFirst = new SongParcel("A Good Song", "Test Artist2", "content://testuri");
        addSongToAvailableList(songFirst);

        SongParcel songMiddle = new SongParcel("Bravo", "David", "content://tests");
        addSongToAvailableList(songMiddle);

        Activity activity = this.getActivity();
        ListView lstAvailableSongs = (ListView) activity.findViewById(R.id.lstAvailableSongs);
        assertEquals(3, lstAvailableSongs.getCount());

        assertListViewItemIsCorrect(lstAvailableSongs, 0, songFirst);
        assertListViewItemIsCorrect(lstAvailableSongs, 1, songMiddle);
        assertListViewItemIsCorrect(lstAvailableSongs, 2, songLast);

        stopMyService();
    }

    private void addSongToAvailableList(SongParcel song) {
        Context context = this.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext();
        Intent addSongIntent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
        addSongIntent.setAction(MyService.ADD_SONG_TO_AVAILABLE_LIST);

        addSongIntent.putExtra(MyService.EXTRA_SONG, song);
        context.startService(addSongIntent);
    }

    private void assertListViewItemIsCorrect(ListView lstView, int index, SongParcel song) {
        Adapter adapter = lstView.getAdapter();
        View row = adapter.getView(0, null, lstView);

        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        assertEquals(song.getTitle(), txtTitle.getText());

        TextView txtArtist = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtArtist);
        assertEquals(song.getArtist(), txtArtist.getText());
    }

    private void stopMyService() {
        this.getActivity().stopService(new Intent(this.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext(), MyService.class));
    }
}
```

I tried using `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2`, but I had problems using the service. It appeared that the service was persisting from test to test because the activity would always display 3 songs.

Am I using `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2` incorrectly or should I be using a different test class?

Comment: You should start-stop service separately for each test.

Comment: can you post your test code?

Comment: @S.D. I tried that, but the service didn't appear to be stopping. Am I stopping it incorrectly?

Comment: @MageWind I think `stopService()` should work. Try to use same intent as the one used to start it. Try using activity instead of target context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I had a bug, so `stopService()` was never being called =P. In `assertListViewItemIsCorrect()`, `adapter.getView(0, null, lstView)` should have been `adapter.getView(index, null, lstView)`. Everything appears to be working fine now.